# How to make bootstrap thumbnail slider with multiple image....?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to make image slider in my page. I tried following but it works great but have problem if use both landscape and portrait image...when i click next arrow carousel height changes and also when i resize window that arrow does not align properly...
Demo : [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ufbm8ymw/)

My code :

```
<div class="container-fluid" style="margin-left:5px;">
<div class="well" style="border:1px solid grey;background: transparent;">
    <div id="myCarousel_Scroller" class="carousel slide">
        <!-- Carousel items -->
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-3">
                        <a href="#x" class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/150x100" alt="Image" class="img-responsive">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-3">
                        <a href="#x" class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/150x100" alt="Image" class="img-responsive">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-3">
                        <a href="#x" class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/150x100" alt="Image" class="img-responsive">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-3">
                        <a href="#x" class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/150x100" alt="Image" class="img-responsive">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--/row-->
            </div>
            <!--/item-->
            <div class="item">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-3">
                        <a href="#x" class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/100x150" alt="Image" class="img-responsive">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-3">
                        <a href="#x" class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/100x150" alt="Image" class="img-responsive">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-3">
                        <a href="#x" class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/100x150" alt="Image" class="img-responsive">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-3">
                        <a href="#x" class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/100x150" alt="Image" class="img-responsive">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--/row-->
            </div>
            <!--/item-->
            <div class="item">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-3">
                        <a href="#x" class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/100x150" alt="Image" class="img-responsive">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-3">
                        <a href="#x" class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/150x100" alt="Image" class="img-responsive">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-3">
                        <a href="#x" class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/100x150" alt="Image" class="img-responsive">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-3">
                        <a href="#x" class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/150x100" alt="Image" class="img-responsive">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--/row-->
            </div>
            <!--/item-->
        </div>
        <!--/carousel-inner--> 
        <a class="left carousel-control center-block" href="#myCarousel_Scroller" data-slide="prev"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></a>
        <a class="right carousel-control center-block" href="#myCarousel_Scroller" data-slide="next"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a>
    </div>
    <!--/myCarousel-->
</div>
<!--/well-->
```

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap has a feature implemented ensures an automated height for images in order for them to be responsive in a carousel.  I added some css as a work-around that fixes the height but leaves the width to be automated. This keeps their aspect ratios.

Here's an updated fiddle: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mijopabe/ufbm8ymw/8/)

**CSS**

```
.carousel-inner img {
    height: 100px;
    max-height: 100px;
    width: auto;
}
.carousel-inner {
    max-height: 110px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <div class="item">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-3">
                    <a href="#x" class="thumbnail">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/100x150" alt="Image" class="img-responsive">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-3">
                    <a href="#x" class="thumbnail">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/150x100" alt="Image" class="img-responsive">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-3">
                    <a href="#x" class="thumbnail">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/100x150" alt="Image" class="img-responsive">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-3">
                    <a href="#x" class="thumbnail">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/150x100" alt="Image" class="img-responsive">
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--/row-->
        </div>
        <!--/item-->
    </div>
    <!--/carousel-inner--> 
    <a class="left carousel-control center-block" href="#myCarousel_Scroller" data-slide="prev"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></a>
    <a class="right carousel-control center-block" href="#myCarousel_Scroller" data-slide="next"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a>
</div>
<!--/myCarousel-->
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, including an explanation of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now.